# settings the "index" property of an elasticsearch object

Tags: elasticsearch

say I have a mapping of objects as such the mapping is:

```
{"my_type":
    {"properties":
        {"name":{"type":"string","store":"yes","index":"not_analyzed"},
         "more":{"type":"object",
                 "properties":{"a_known_number":{"type":"long","index":"yes"},
                               "some_json_object":{"type":"object"}
                              }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know what sub fields the "some_json_object" will have, but i DO know that I only want to store this object, but not index any of it's sub-fields.
Can I do:

```
    {"my_type":
    {"properties":
        {"name":{"type":"string","store":"yes","index":"not_analyzed"},
         "more":{"type":"object",
                 "properties":{"a_known_number":{"type":"long","index":"yes"},
                               "some_json_object":{"type":"object","store":"yes","index":"no"}
                              }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and affect all of the resulting sub-fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't specify the entire "object" as not indexed. However you can use dynamic_templates (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/root-object-type/) to do this:

```
{
   "my_type":{
      "properties":{
         "name":{
            "type":"string",
            "store":"yes",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
         }
      },
      "dynamic_templates":[
         {
            "stored_json_object_template":{
               "path_match":"some_json_object.*",
               "mapping":{
                  "store":"yes",
                  "index":"no"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This tells the mapper to map all properties for "some_json_object" as stored strings.

**Update**
Removed type from mapping in order to match all property types (match_path => path_match).

**Update 2**
If you then create an index:

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "my_type":{
         "properties":{
            "name":{
               "type":"string",
               "store":"yes",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            }
         },
         "dynamic_templates":[
            {
               "stored_json_object_template":{
                  "path_match":"some_json_object.*",
                  "mapping":{
                     "store":"yes",
                     "index":"no"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

and index an object:

```
{
   "Name":"Henrik",
   "some_json_object":{
      "string":"string",
      "long":12345
   }
}
```

it will then get the following mapping:

```
{
   "testindex":{
      "my_type":{
         "dynamic_templates":[
            {
               "stored_json_object_template":{
                  "mapping":{
                     "index":"no",
                     "store":"yes"
                  },
                  "path_match":"some_json_object.*"
               }
            }
         ],
         "properties":{
            "name":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "store":true,
               "omit_norms":true,
               "index_options":"docs"
            },
            "some_json_object":{
               "properties":{
                  "long":{
                     "type":"long",
                     "index":"no",
                     "store":true
                  },
                  "string":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "index":"no",
                     "store":true
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I do that to a sub_object? I revised the question to explain better.

Also, I guess it can only be done to type "string" and not type "long" or "boolean" since everything can convert to string.